# Primevue panelmenu component expand icon position change

Tags: primevue

In the Primevue `Panelmenu` component, how can I move the expand icon from the beginning to the end of the menu item? I am using Vue version 3, composition API and Primevue version 3.29.2.

[panel menu picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXfNn.jpg)

Thanks